# Python Serial communition with device

Tags: python, serial-port, port, distance, period

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnHLc.jpg)

I am making serial port communication device from a genious guy's work  instructables.com.

It will measure the distance of the hamster's running in a day or month.

Using 4, 6 pin of the serial port cable, if the hamster runs, the device can count the numbers how many time did she run.

When I run the py file with Python27 like below, some errors occure.
"python hamster-serial.py progress.txt"

I cannot understand what's going on.
I am using windows8 and Python2.7 version.

Could you check my source, please?

```html
import datetime
import serial
import sys

# Check for commandline argument. The first argument is the the name of the program.
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
  print "Usage: python %s [Out File]" % sys.argv[0]
  exit()

# Open the serial port we'll use the pins on and the file we'll write to.
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS1")

# Open the file we're going to write the results to.
f = open(sys.argv[1], 'a')

# Bring DTR to 1. This will be shorted to DSR when the switch is activated as the wheel turns.
ser.setDTR(1)

# The circumferance of the wheel.
circ = 0.000396 # miles
# Total distance traveled in this run of the program.
distance = 0.0

print "%s] Starting logging." % datetime.datetime.now()
start = datetime.datetime.now()

# This function a period of the wheel to a speed of the hamster.
def toSpeed(period):
  global circ
  seconds = period.days * 24 * 60 * 60 + period.seconds + period.microseconds / 1000000.
  return circ / (seconds / 60. / 60.)
  
# Waits for the DSR pin on the serial port to turn off. This indicates that the
# switch has turned off and the magnet is no longer over the switch.
def waitForPinOff():
  while ser.getDSR() == 1:
    1 # Don't do anything while we wait.

# Waits for the DSR pin on the serial port to turn on. This indicates that the
# switch has turned on and the magnet is current over the switch.
def waitForPinOn():
  while ser.getDSR() == 0:
    1 # Don't do anything while we wait.

# The main loop of the program.
while 1:
  waitForPinOn()
  
  # Calculate the speed.
  end = datetime.datetime.now()
  period = end - start
  start = end
  speed = toSpeed(period)
  # Increment the distance.
  distance = distance + circ
  
  waitForPinOff()
  
  # We'll calculate the time the switch was held on too so but this isn't too useful.
  hold = datetime.datetime.now() - start
 
  # If the switch bounces or the hamster doesn't make a full revolution then
  # it might seem like the hamster is running really fast. If the speed is
  # more than 4 mph then ignore it, because the hamster can't run that fast.
  if speed < 4.0:
    # Print out our speed and distance for this session.
    print "%s] Distance: %.4f miles Speed: %.2f mph" % (datetime.datetime.now(), distance, speed)
      
    # Log it to and flush the file so it actually gets written.
    f.write("%s\t%.2f\n" % (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%D %T"), speed))
    f.flush()
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS1")` is for a linux machine, on windows you'll need something like `ser = serial.Serial("COM1")` (you can check what COM do you need in the device manager).

As a side note,

```
def waitForPinOff():
   while ser.getDSR() == 1:
      1 # Don't do anything while we wait.
```

Will eat you CPU. You are better of with:

```
def waitForPinOff():
   while ser.getDSR() == 1:
      time.sleep(1) # Don't do anything while we wait.
```

Comment: Wow!! Unbelievable!  Just now, you save my life...in my the most important moment!  I am really appreciate you!

Comment: I think, it is succeeded! Now I will reserch and investigate. Thanks for your great help!

Comment: >>> 2016-08-02 14:38:34.145000] Starting logging.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\Python27\hamster-serial.py", line 54, in <module>
    speed = toSpeed(period)
  File "C:\Python27\hamster-serial.py", line 31, in toSpeed
    return circ / (seconds / 60. / 60.)
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Comment: Your func runs end right after start. Can you explain the inputs your system has? What is the requirement for 1 and 0?

Also, assuming the switch is on when you run the code, your start and end will be equal.

Comment: OK, you should change `seconds = period.days * 24 * 60 * 60 + period.seconds + period.microseconds / 1000000` to `seconds = period.days * 24 * 60 * 60 + period.seconds + period.microseconds / 1000000.0` so the result wont be rounded to integer. Currently a result smaller than one second returns 0.

Comment: Thank you for your great help! I will be so happy to learn and study Python!

Comment: >>> 2016-08-03 21:22:46.808000] Starting logging.
2016-08-03 21:22:55.574000] Distance: 0.0053 miles Speed: 2.16 mph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\Python27\hamster-serial.py", line 70, in <module>
    f.write("%s\t%.2f\n" %(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%D %T"), speed))
ValueError: Invalid format string

Comment: IT's almost done! the last valueError is the file write.  I am studying and trying to do by myself but it is still difficult!  Thanks Aruj!!

Comment: You have a reference for strftime formats (here)[https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior]. You probably want something like `"%s\t%.2f\n" %(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"), speed)`

Comment: Arju!!  Finally, I got the perfect result!

Comment: 06/08/16 11:02:03 2.76
06/08/16 11:02:04 2.85
06/08/16 11:02:05 2.77
06/08/16 11:02:05 2.28
06/08/16 11:02:06 2.94
06/08/16 11:02:06 3.80
06/08/16 11:02:06 3.80
06/08/16 11:02:11 1.13
06/08/16 11:02:12 1.72
06/08/16 11:02:13 2.12
06/08/16 11:02:14 1.98
06/08/16 11:02:14 2.28
06/08/16 11:02:15 2.23
06/08/16 11:02:15 2.53
06/08/16 11:02:16 2.28
06/08/16 11:02:17 2.40
06/08/16 11:02:17 2.47
06/08/16 11:02:18 2.47
06/08/16 11:02:18 3.80
06/08/16 11:02:20 2.28
06/08/16 11:02:21 1.06
06/08/16 11:02:22 1.79

Comment: It is my progress.txt

Comment: I found that the cause of the error was the setting of magnetic reed switch!

Comment: I am so appreciated to you and the original source programmer!

Comment: And also you can see my work in my website!  kimyongim.com/220777899822   Please, give me any advice any time!  Thank you again, Arju!